# How can I call a webservice after an action on a User Control?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, web-services, user-controls

I'd like to call a webservice function (.asmx) when a user click on a checkbox, generated by a .NET (WEbForms) User Control :

```
CheckBox chb = new CheckBox();
chb.InputAttributes.Add("value", "my_id_00");
chb.Text = "Title 00";
myPanel.Controls.Add(chb);
```

and pass the parameter "value" (so, `my_id_00`).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple ways:

1) Add a JavaScript onClick Event for each Check box. The JavaScript function can call the webservice.

```
chb.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format("CallMyWebService({0});", "my_id_00");

<script type="text/javascript">
    function CallMyWebService(value){
        //Code to Call Web Service passing value
    }
</script>
```

2) Add a ServerSide Event Handler for the Checkbox. Event Handler extracts the value and calls the webservice

```
chb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkBox_CheckedChanged);
```

3) If JQuery is an Option, Attach the Javascript onClick Function to each Checkbox on the Page Ready Event.